# MAGMI is not importing Images from remote URL's

Tags: magento, magmi

I am attempting to import products in to Magento via MAGMI.  The CSV is being generated by a different application.  The CSV file is as follows

```
sku,name,image,image_label
BLE02U,Hand Cream,http://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket_name/product_codes/50b82c2b315bb06f5a000037/product_code_images/original.jpg,awesome image
```

When I run the MAGMI there are no errors reported. The products appear in the backend of Magento but the images are broken. Looking in the media folder of my local magento install suggests that no images have been downloaded as there is only images from products I have uploaded by hand.

I have the Image attributes processor installed and I am renaming images with the following regex

```
re::((\d|[a-z]){24})\/product_code_images\/original\.([a-z]{3})::$1\.$3
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This might be a good question for [http://magento.stackexchange.com/](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK turns out I had configured MAGMI incorrectly. I did not have the root magento path set up. Note by default this will not be correct and you will have to adjust it.

Comment: where did you setup root magento path pls help

Comment: Despite this being 6 years old, I'll answer in case someone else finds this. Updating the magento root path worked for me. Adjust that root path either in the web interface or in `magmi/conf/magmi.ini`

Answer (score 0):

@Muk (comment below): Let's say you installed magmi in your rootfolder, then go to:
www.yourshop.com/magmi/web/magmi.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but:

PHP Warning:  curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in ...

I just disabled open_basedir and it worked like a charm.

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
- Release:        12.04
- Codename:       precise

Magmi v0.7.20_git